# Displaying factors and levels with logistic regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I have a dataframe `model.vars` containing discretized data on which to perform logistical regression, as follows:

```
for(i in varnames)
{
  modelformula = paste("dep_var~ ", as.factor(i))
  modelfits[[i]] = glm(as.formula(modelformula), 
                       data=model.vars ,na.action="na.exclude", 
                       family=binomial(link = "logit"))
}
```

This gets in turn converted to a dataframe using

```
fits = ldply(modelfits, function(x) {
  as.data.frame((coef(summary(x))), 
                row.names=varnames)})
```

However, the resulting output stored in `modelfits` does not contain a column specifying the relevant level labels for each discretized variable. Rather, I get something like

```
     .id              Estimate   Std. Error  zscore     Pr(>|z|)     abs.zscore
1 Twenty_80.age     -0.6911487  0.2813814   -2.456270   1.403875e-02    2.4562
2 Ten_80_10.age     -1.0021909  0.2682952   -3.735403   1.874144e-04    3.735403
3 Twenty_80.score   -0.7023356  0.3315694   -2.118216   3.415679e-02    2.118216
```

Unfortunately, we need the output as a dataframe (not a list). What would be the best way to add, say, an extra column giving us the level labels? For example, printing out the raw `modelfits` variable has statements like:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Twenty_80.score[ 11, 19)  Twenty_80.score[ 19, 31)  Twenty_80.score[ 31,312]
```

I would like these listed in the `fits` dataframe above as well.